# COALESCE with SUM with Join table are not calculation correct

Tags: mysql, workbench

I'm working on the Join table with union of 5 different table together
As I have written code for the union all tables and it's working fine without a join table

as you can see the code

```
    SELECT  sku,
        sum(units_ordered) as units_ordered
FROM   (
        SELECT sku, units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT sku, units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order_de
        UNION ALL
        SELECT sku, units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order_es
        UNION ALL
        SELECT sku, units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order_fr
        UNION ALL
        SELECT sku, units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order_it
       ) AllMarketplace
group by sku
ORDER BY units_ordered DESC;
```

as you can see  the result in the first link on db fiddle

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nbGcxACaf4doHRssJDSyRN/0 and the outcome is correct

[image]

You can see "H-Root-M012S-Black 87" which is correct a total of QTY stock.

I need them to join with one of the other tables as left join.
Here is a code in db fiddle

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dxqsU4enjRYqk7du7VEB4d/0

this is code i wrote

```
SELECT 
    ls.sku                                  AS list_sku,
    COALESCE(MIN(suo.sku), 'Not Sold')      AS sold_sku,
    COALESCE(SUM(suo.units_ordered), 0)     AS units_ordered
FROM
    (SELECT 
        COALESCE(MIN(sku), 'Not Sold')      AS sold_sku,
        COALESCE(SUM(units_ordered), 0)     AS units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  
        COALESCE(MIN(sku), 'Not Sold')      AS sold_sku,
        COALESCE(SUM(units_ordered), 0)     AS units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order_de
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        COALESCE(MIN(sku), 'Not Sold')      AS sold_sku,
        COALESCE(SUM(units_ordered), 0)     AS units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order_es
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        COALESCE(MIN(sku), 'Not Sold')      AS sold_sku,
        COALESCE(SUM(units_ordered), 0)     AS units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order_fr
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  
        COALESCE(MIN(sku), 'Not Sold')      AS sold_sku,
        COALESCE(SUM(units_ordered), 0)     AS units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order_it
    ) as t1,
    tbl_list_sku AS ls
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl_sku_units_order AS suo ON suo.sku = ls.sku
GROUP BY ls.sku
ORDER BY units_ordered DESC;
```

And it's returned fine, but the calculation is wrong

[image]

I have suspect it due to group issue? I have to tweak it on the group but all results have returned same results along with right or inner join tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL should be like this:

```
SELECT 
    ls.sku                                  AS list_sku,
    COALESCE(MIN(suo.sku), 'Not Sold')      AS sold_sku,
    COALESCE(SUM(suo.units_ordered), 0)     AS units_ordered
FROM
    (SELECT sku,
        COALESCE(MIN(sku), 'Not Sold')      AS sold_sku,
        COALESCE(SUM(units_ordered), 0)     AS units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT sku,  
        COALESCE(MIN(sku), 'Not Sold')      AS sold_sku,
        COALESCE(SUM(units_ordered), 0)     AS units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order_de
        UNION ALL
        SELECT sku,
        COALESCE(MIN(sku), 'Not Sold')      AS sold_sku,
        COALESCE(SUM(units_ordered), 0)     AS units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order_es
        UNION ALL
        SELECT sku,
        COALESCE(MIN(sku), 'Not Sold')      AS sold_sku,
        COALESCE(SUM(units_ordered), 0)     AS units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order_fr
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  sku,
        COALESCE(MIN(sku), 'Not Sold')      AS sold_sku,
        COALESCE(SUM(units_ordered), 0)     AS units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order_it
    ) as t1 join 
    tbl_list_sku AS ls on t1.sku = ls.sku
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl_sku_units_order AS suo ON suo.sku = ls.sku
GROUP BY ls.sku
ORDER BY units_ordered DESC;
```

## EDIT-1

```
SELECT 
    ls.sku                                  AS list_sku,
    COALESCE(MIN(suo.sku), 'Not Sold')      AS sold_sku,
    COALESCE(SUM(suo.units_ordered), 0)     AS units_ordered
FROM tbl_list_sku AS ls left join
    (SELECT sku,
        COALESCE(MIN(sku), 'Not Sold')      AS sold_sku,
        COALESCE(SUM(units_ordered), 0)     AS units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT sku,  
        COALESCE(MIN(sku), 'Not Sold')      AS sold_sku,
        COALESCE(SUM(units_ordered), 0)     AS units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order_de
        UNION ALL
        SELECT sku,
        COALESCE(MIN(sku), 'Not Sold')      AS sold_sku,
        COALESCE(SUM(units_ordered), 0)     AS units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order_es
        UNION ALL
        SELECT sku,
        COALESCE(MIN(sku), 'Not Sold')      AS sold_sku,
        COALESCE(SUM(units_ordered), 0)     AS units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order_fr
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  sku,
        COALESCE(MIN(sku), 'Not Sold')      AS sold_sku,
        COALESCE(SUM(units_ordered), 0)     AS units_ordered
        FROM   tbl_sku_units_order_it
    ) as t1 on t1.sku = ls.sku
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl_sku_units_order AS suo ON suo.sku = ls.sku
GROUP BY ls.sku
ORDER BY units_ordered DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, it returns calculation correct however it return only 3 row of data, which it should be more than 110 of row of data

Comment: Which of table contains 110 rows, does union all sql's or "ls" or "tbl_sku_units_order" table?

Comment: tbl_list_sku contains 110 rows and I know 44 row of all Order ( in T1) return with 44 rows that it has sold

Comment: I have updated the answer with EDIT-1, use the SQL after EDIT-1 it will solve.

Comment: that it seems it down to " t1 on t1.sku=ls.sku " which I didn't put it. thank you for an answer. I should know better, seems I overlook it.